# Using python and skype4py to receive and send chat

Tags: python, skype4py

I would like to be able to read messages from a specific user in skype using skype4py then send an automated response based upon the message back to the skype chat window. That way a user could message me and get an automated response saying that I'm currently busy or whatever. I really just need to know how to read and send skype chat using skype4py in python. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Here is a goog example: https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py/blob/master/examples/SkypeBot.py#L17

Comment: I haven't :(. I really don't quite understand how to implement skype4py. I'm currently learning python and found a great example of how to send messages to skype but couldn't see how to get them from skype and use them. I was looking for an easy shortcut. Thanks for the example Anna.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to give you all the answer so that you can improve your coding skills but I will give you some clues:
1)Use boolean values for being activated and deactivated
2)Set a command that activates and deactivates
3) set a value that if reaceived or sent chat and true/false then reply.
Gave you a lot of clues! Good look!.